# ng-if is condition is not in Ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to hide the row of `ng-repeat` using `ng-if` condition?

We are trying to restrict the displaying the `ng-repeat` row using `ng-if` condition. Here, I'm checking for the value **five** and **three** if it is not there then I need to hide the row.

```js
 angular
   .module('myApp', [])
   .controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.comments = [{
       type: 'one'
     }, {
       type: 'two'
     }, {
       type: 'three'
     }, {
       type: 'four'
     }]
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="data in comments">
        <td ng-if="data.type == 'five' ">five</td>
        <td ng-if="data.type == 'three' ">Three</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

```
five Three five Three five Three five Three
```

**Expected output:**

```
Three Three Three Three
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: In your array have not available "five" value so, it will not gives you output into 'five' value it gives three value one time right ?

Comment: As @VijayPatel said, it only gives `three` one time. but you said `five Three five Three five Three five Three` is my output. how is it possible?

Comment: function TodoCtrl($scope) { $scope.comments = [ {type:'one'},{type:'two'},{type:'three'},{type:'four'} ] }

Comment: <div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
       <table>
        <tr ng-repeat = "data in comments">
            <td ng-if="data.type == 'five' ">
            five
            </td>
             <td ng-if="data.type == 'three' ">
            Three  
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: five  Three 
five  Three
five  Three
five  Three

Comment: @RajathShetty Right now your code give only three once only.
It's better to initialized your angular module with a name and defined it's scope rather then making it global. Do you want to check if the value is not three, still need to show the three as row output ?

Comment: @Loading.. *Fun fact:* his output is correct while using older versions of angular, for example 1.1.0

Comment: now i changed my app.js to   // Define a new module for our app
var Condition = angular.module("Condition", []);

Condition.controller('TypeController',['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.comments = [
        {type:'three'}
    ]
});  my output is 
five Three.

Comment: I'm using 1.5.8/angular.min.js version.

Comment: @RajathShetty can you explain your problem again Because I think you got the proper result?

Comment: Its working now.Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always preferred to initialize your angular module with a name instead of making it blank.

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates
>   to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a
>   clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM. For more details see
>   below snippet... More information [ngif](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.comments = [
    {
        type: 'one'
    }, {
        type: 'two'
    }, {
        type: 'three'
    }, {
        type: 'four'
    }
    ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div >
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in comments">
                <td ng-if="data.type == 'five'"> five </td>
                <td ng-if="data.type == 'three'"> Three </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I Tried the same code and it is still showing the output as  
five Three
  In Console iIm getting 2 errors :Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
angular.js:4640Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…udflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A390)

Comment: @RajathShetty See my code, it's not giving any errors, what's the problem now ?

Comment: Thank you,Its working for me.I checked again its working fine, anjular js Version mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **you can use multiple directives on the same element,** thus achieving your desired output. Have a look at this example in which, on the same element, I placed `ngRepeat`, `ngIf`, `ngClick` and `ngBind`.

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function() {
    this.myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    this.showNum = function(num) {
      console.log('You clicked on', num);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="listItem in vm.myList" 
          ng-if="listItem % 2 === 0" 
          ng-click="vm.showNum(listItem);" 
          ng-bind="listItem"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This work perfectly fine with <li></li> but  I want this same condition to work in <td>,/td> that is not working.

Comment: I don't understand you. For example, the output of your code is *Three*, not the one you've listed. If it works perfectly with `<li>`, why won't it work in your example? It's the same principle.

Answer (score -1):

I think that u did not add five in your comment array

```
$scope.comments = [ {type:'one'},{type:'two'},{type:'three'},{type:'four'},{type:'five'} ]
```

Comment: here I'm checking the ng-if condition for for  type five and I don't want to display that value in  row of  ng-repeat,but in output it is displaying five,this is not correct,

Comment: I modified my js file as // Define a new module for our app
var Condition = angular.module("Condition", []);

Condition.controller('TypeController',['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.comments = [
      [ {type:'one'},{type:'two'},{type:'three'},{type:'four'} ] 
    ]
});   still I'm getting 5 in my output. my code  <table>
        I'm getting console error as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
angular.js:4640 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]